# Can anyone tell me the precision of Real_Matrix in ada

Tags: arrays, matrix, ada

Does anyone know the precision of Real_Matrix in ada, using the below package?

```
   with Ada.Numerics.Real_Arrays
```

And is there anyway of increasing it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [LRM](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-G-3-1.html#I8301), "The library package Numerics.Real_Arrays is declared pure and defines the same types and subprograms as Numerics.Generic_Real_Arrays, except that the predefined type Float is systematically substituted for Real'Base throughout."

This means that the precision of Real_Matrix values will be that of the predefined Float type, which can be ascertained for your platform as the value of [Float'Digits](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-3-5-8.html).

(Interestingly, the wording suggests a textual substitution of 'Float' for all 'Real' and Real'Base subprogram arguments, however, GNAT GPL 2012's version of Real_Arrays simply instantiates the Generic_Real_Arrays package with Float.)

Increasing the precision can be done by either utilizing one of the higher precision instantiations: Long_Real_Arrays or Long_Long_Real_Arrays, or by defining your own floating point type with the desired precision and instantiating Generic_Real_Arrays with it.